# Using CSS1 how can I hover over an image and swap it with a different image?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm being forced to use this browser called Fresco by ANT. In it's specs it says it can handle CSS1. So I'm trying to create a link that has an image, and when hovered over, have the image change.

I've tried:

```
<td width="30% valign="top" align="left">
<a href="someFilePath"><div id="changeImage"></div></a>
</td>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
#changeImage{
background: url(somefilepath1);
width: 218px;
height: 52px;
}

#changeImage:hover{
background: url(somefilepath2);
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc... But in this awkward browser called Fresco, it doesn't show the image at all. I'm not even sure if this is considered CSS1 approved? I've googled and found CSS1 stylings, but nothing to exactly define what I'm trying to do. Any web guru have any tips on this for me?

Comment: May I be the first to ask why you are bothering with a web browser released 20 years ago?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it has trouble reading the psuedo :hover. Technically this was implemented in the early days to be used with only an anchor. I believe Internet **Exploder** 6 has :hover support only for anchor elements still. This soon has been changed to support all elements on a page.

I would say, try using a sprite sheet where the backgrounds are loaded already and changing the background position of this element. Which would be best practice to do anyways because, you will get instant action, instead of triggering a server request and having the user wait for the new content to arrive.

Here is more detail on the technique and CSS1 does support the background position element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position